# asp.net image jpeg not saving correctly

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload

I am trying to save a jpeg image in an uploads folder which has correct permissions setup. When I test the file is being saved (eg: images/uploads/Winter.jpg) but if I try to view the image in my browser or if I attempt to open the image using anything else the image does not display.

I think that the file is not being encoded correctly before saving it to disk but am not very experienced dealing with the saving of files, encoding. Does the below code look ok or do I need to encode the file being uploaded somehow before saving it to disk?

```
String imgPath = "newsletter\\images\\uploads\\";

String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.PostedFile.FileName);

filepath = imgPath + filename;

filepath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + filepath; 
upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
```

The file saves to the correct folder but is only 150bytes in size. If I try to browse to the file and view it with an image viewer it does not display correctly.

Comment: What is the size of the file? Do you have it inside button click event?

Comment: When you browse directly to the folder on the server is the image there? Can you view it with an image viewer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - The function is called from another function with the FileUpload control passed in to the saveImage function as 'upload'.

Comment: You answered none of my questions and also ignored Oded's comment. I'll give this another shot. What is the size of the file after you save it on server? Do you call the code from `Page_Load` or button click event?

Comment: Ok OK.. I was checking if I could view the image through an image viewer so that I could answer oded's question. The answer is no, it does not open in an image viewer.

The image size is 150bytes. The saveImage function is called from another functon that is called from a button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding shouldn't be a problem - the raw data isn't changing. However, it's possible the browser isn't sending all the data, or that the upload control is deleting the data before you're saving it.

Make sure that you call .SaveAs() *before* the page begins unloading, and *before* any additional postbacks. I think we'll need to see more surrounding code to help further.

Another note - by allowing the existing file extension to be used, you're allowing users to upload .aspx files, which could subsequently be executed through a request. Safe filenames are GUIDs and whitelisted file extensions. Using un-sanitized uploaded path information is very dangerous. If you re-use filenames, sanitize them to alphanumerics.